# Let G be a cubic graph with q edges and girth$\ge$4. How many paths of length 3 are in G?

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a cubic graph with q edges and girth $\ge$ 4. How many paths of length 3 are in G?

I only know that 3p=2q.

Answer (score 3):

Pick any edge $vw$. Because both $v$ and $w$ have degree $3$, there are two other edges out of $v$ and two other edges out of $w$. Because the girth is at least $4$, the are no $3$-cycles, so there is no vertex $x$ with edges $vx$ and $wx$.

In other words, the other edges out of $v$ and $w$ all go to different vertices, and no matter which edge $vw$ we pick, the part of the graph around edge $vw$ looks like this:

[image: graph]

This is enough to answer the question. How many paths of length $3$ have $vw$ as their middle edge? From there, how many paths are there total?

Comment: there are 4q paths. Omg it's so easy with your explanation! Thank you！